# SSL error: redirected you too many times

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

my htaccess file actually contained this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /index.php/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

then I added

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.in/$1 [R,L]
```

Which is causing infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Cant make it, need some help

Comment: Where is the server hosted? Is `https` actually listening on 443, or you're using a load balancer/proxy forwarding?